# Can't autowire a ScoreManager in optaplanner while using a custom solver xml configuration

Tags: xml, spring-boot, scheduling, optaplanner, timetable

Hello im using optaplanner, i've created a custom xml file solver like below :
[image]

and in my controller i've tried to autowire my SolverManager [image]

The problem is when using the default SolverManager the ScoreManager is autowired successfully but here it return always an error that it couldn't be autowired is theire a solution to that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which is the full set of annotations you're adding (if any) to your custom solverManager ? Looks like SpringBoot can't uniquely identify exactly which solverManager to inject (as far as my very basic SpringBoot abilities can tell) - maybe you should just add the `@Primary` annotation ?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please explain what is the motivation for using a custom `SolverManager`? If you need a custom solver configuration, it can be achieved by setting the property `optaplanner.solver-config-xml`. Please see the [Spring Boot integration section](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#integrationWithSpringBoot) in the documentation.